# MySQL statement returning too many rows

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to return all the orders from a particular person, I have two tables, a person and an order and using a join, it does return orders of the person but for each order it returns the square amount of that order, for example if there two orders that are the same it will return 4 of those orders.

```
SELECT 
  o.* 
FROM
  orderr o 
  LEFT JOIN person p 
    ON p.personID = o.personID 
WHERE p.first_name = ?
```

Comment: Try adding `DISTINCT`?  Like: `SELECT DISTINCT o.*`.  Or maybe you need to remove the `NULL` rows, since you are `LEFT JOIN`ing: `WHERE p.first_name IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Your query should work, see this fiddle for a simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e4b7/2/0 . Something is wrong in your data, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      o.* 
    FROM
      orderr o 
      LEFT JOIN person p 
        ON p.personID = o.personID 
    WHERE p.first_name = ?
```